# ng-switch ng-repeat to create table

Tags: angularjs

Following is my `$scope.fields`

```
[{"Puts":"109","name":"payments","Role":"admin","Entries":"109"},
{"Puts":"8","name":"employees","Role":"admin","Entries":"8"},
{"Puts":"3","name":"offices","Role":"admin","Entries":"3"},
{"Puts":"3","name":"productlines","Role":"admin","Entries":"3"},
{"Puts":"37","name":"products","Role":"admin","Entries":"37"},
{"Puts":"973","name":"orderdetails","Role":"admin","Entries":"973"},
{"Puts":"95","name":"orders","Role":"admin","Entries":"95"},
{"Puts":"37","name":"customers","Role":"admin","Entries":"37"},
{"Puts":"1265","name":"Total","Entries":"1265"}]
```

Using below I can form a table

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Entries</th>
        <th>Puts</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="F in fields">
        <td>{{F.name}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Role}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Entries}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Puts}}</td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I want last row bolder.

Can I do that using ng-switch inside ng-repeat?

I tried a lot but couldn't get through.

P.S. - can use angularjs 1.0.8 only.

Thanks in advance.

~ajit

Comment: I'm unsure of your question, you want the last row of the `<th>` to be bold? you only have one row with `<th>` and they don't have any angular expressions, so it seems like an HTML question, though an example of your expected result and your desired result would help.

Comment: you asking about using ng-switch but I cannot see ng-switch in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Steve mentioned: you can easily style the last row via CSS:

```
.my-table tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But if have to do this in Angular you can, for instance, use the `$index` property in expressions. So when the statement `$index == (fields.length-1)` hits `true` you're on the last row. Now combine this with a `ng-class`:

**MARKUP**

```
<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="field in fields"
      ng-class="{ 'table-total': $index == (fields.length-1) }">
    <td>{{ field.Puts }}</td>
    <td>{{ field.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ field.Role }}</td>
    <td>{{ field.Entries }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-total {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jINvRFZEywFfYd9EhGDe?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the bold styling, you could use a CSS selector to style the last row in the table explicitly.

```
tr:last-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

If you only want this to affect the body of the table (which looks likely from your data) then preface the selector with tbody.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `ng-switch` but there is more easy way to do it...

`ng-repeat` has `$last` variable which is `boolean`, so if you can combine it with `ng-class` you will change row class if it is last row...

here is example code...

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Entries</th>
        <th>Puts</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="F in fields"
        ng-class="{'last-row: $last}">
        <td>{{F.name}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Role}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Entries}}</td>
        <td>{{F.Puts}}</td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

last row of the table will have `.last-row` class...